# What are the differences in string literals between C#, Visual Basic.NET, and Managed C++?

Tags: .net, string-literals

I'm referring to the syntax for writing strings in code, including multiline strings and verbatim strings.

(Context: I'm working on a tool that scans code, and it's important to determine when tokens are inside a string.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick breakdown between languages

- Managed C++: Supports string literals much in the way that vanilla C,C++ or C# does.  That is strings are designated by " and allow for character escape sequences in the middle via a \.
- C#: Supports normal string literals (essentially same syntax as Managed C++) and verbatim string literals.  Verbatim string literals start with `@"` and do not support character escape sequences (with the exception of "" which designates a single ").  They can span multiple lines and all whitespace is significant
- VB.Net: Strings are delimited by "'s and no escape sequences are supported

Answer (score 0):

basic syntax is same

```
string csharp;    // C#
string cPlusPlus; // C++
```

see following for better insight

[**string class**](http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/strings/header-string.html) (C++) and [**string class**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe(VS.71).aspx) (C#)